# Register Page Using SQLite Crash Android App

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm trying to create a login/register page on my Android app using SQLite. Right now my app is crashing in the Register page (where you create a new account using an email/password. Below are the codes for my register page and the DatabaseHelper page. Note that my app says that the error is in the helper.insertContact(c) line of SignUp, which leads us to an error in the insertContact method in DatabaseHelper.

this is the log cat:

```
02-16 22:20:47.236 10925-10925/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
02-16 22:20:47.236 10925-10925/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
02-16 22:20:47.405 10925-10925/com.example.reynaldo.project1 W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.reynaldo.project1-1/lib/x86
02-16 22:20:47.430 10925-10925/com.example.reynaldo.project1 I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.example.reynaldo.project1, real application class is null.
02-16 22:20:48.833 10925-10925/com.example.reynaldo.project1 W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.reynaldo.project1-1/lib/x86
02-16 22:20:49.066 10925-10925/com.example.reynaldo.project1 W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
02-16 22:20:49.328 10925-10968/com.example.reynaldo.project1 I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-16 22:20:49.328 10925-10968/com.example.reynaldo.project1 D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
02-16 22:20:49.348 10925-10968/com.example.reynaldo.project1 E/EGL_emulation: tid 10968: eglSurfaceAttrib(1174): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
02-16 22:20:49.348 10925-10968/com.example.reynaldo.project1 W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9903de60, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
```

This is the SignUp code

```
public class SignUp extends Activity {
static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;
String mCurrentPhotoPath;


DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.signup);
}

public void onSignUpClick (View v){
    if (v.getId() == R.id.Bsignupbutton){
        EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFemail);
        EditText pass1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFpass1);
        EditText pass2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFpass2);

        String emailstr= email.getText().toString();
        String pass1str = pass1.getText().toString();
        String pass2str = pass2.getText().toString();

        if (!pass1str.equals(pass2str)){
            Toast pass = Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Passwords don't match!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            pass.show();
        }

        else{
            Contact c = new Contact();
            c.setEmail(emailstr);
            c.setPass(pass1str);

            helper.insertContact(c);

        }


    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File

        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                    "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the DatabaseHelper:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contacts.db";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "contacts";
private static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String COLUMN_PASS = "pass";
private static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
SQLiteDatabase db;
private static final String TABLE_CREATE = "create table contacts (id integer primary key not null , " +
        "email text not null, pass text not null);";

public DatabaseHelper (Context context){

    super (context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
    db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
    this.db = db;

}

public void insertContact(Contact c){
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    String query = "select" + "from contacts";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query , null);
    int count = cursor.getCount();

    values.put(COLUMN_ID, count);
    values.put(COLUMN_EMAIL, c.getEmail());
    values.put(COLUMN_PASS, c.getPass());

    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close();
}

public String searchPass(String email){
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "select email, password from " + TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    String a, b;
    b = "not found";
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            a = cursor.getString(0);
            b = cursor.getString(1);

            if(a.equals(email)){
                b = cursor.getString(1);
                break;
            }
        }
        while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return b;
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
    String query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;
    db.execSQL(query);
    this.onCreate(db);

}
}
```

Comment: Please show the actual logcat, not just say what the error points at

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead in your class

```
private DatabaseHelper helper;
```

and move the initialization into onCreate where `this` has been setup within the Android lifecycle

```
helper  = new DatabaseHelper(this);
```

Also, query is wrong.

```
String query = "select" + "from contacts";
```

And you really shouldn't store plaintext passwords in a database, but that won't cause your app to crash...

Comment: Run the code in your head. What are you selecting? The string is `selectfrom contacts`, which is 1) invalid sql 2)  selecting no columns

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    public void insertContact(Contact c){
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        String query = "select * from contacts";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query , null);
         int count=0;
        if(cursor!null)
        {
         count = cursor.getCount();
        }

        values.put(COLUMN_ID, count);
        values.put(COLUMN_EMAIL, c.getEmail());
        values.put(COLUMN_PASS, c.getPass());

        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        db.close();
    }
```

Comment: `new DatabaseHelper` will still crash the app where it's at in the question